# Gdal_translate does not affect image when only using 2 points

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I want to do a 2 point georeference because I don't want to warp the image. I just want to rotate and scale it. I tried using the below arguments, which runs with no errors. It imbedds the points into the new image and creates a geotiff correctly. Put when I add it to QGIS it doesn't show and zooms to south america. If I add a third point it works fine.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 -b 1 -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -gcp 969.861598523485 686.215904522596 -74.1084636189044 40.6942092010138 -gcp 5820.04006096547 3893.28866195693 -74.103665985167 40.6958183083443 "C:\InFile.tif" "C:\OutFile.tif"
```

Answer (score 1):

Warping functions in GDAL support only polynomial warping with orders 1-3, and thin plate spline. I guess that QGIS is using the same defaults than gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html

> -order  order of polynomial used for warping (1 to 3). The default
>   is to select a polynomial order based on the number of GCPs.

1st order polynomial transformation requires at least 3 GCPs.

GDAL supports also thin plate spline transformation but it requires also at least three GCPs (see https://elonen.iki.fi/code/tpsdemo/index.html) so it seems that you out of luck with GDAL if you have only two ground control points.

An option that could work for you is to use the the georeferencer plugin of QGIS and select "linear" as the transformation method.

Comment: Doesn't let me use -tps with only 2 GCPs. Gives me an error. `ERROR 1: Unable to compute a GCP_TPS based transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates`